# How to make XElement.Parse Attributes with ? and slash symbols

Tags: c#, xelement

I am attempting to use C# XElement to parse html.
In HTML, src attributes have urls and query strings containing ? and /
Is it possible to make them parsable?

Comment: That will work just fine.  However, HTML is usually not valid XML; consider using HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: It does not. It will throw
'<' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'. Line 709, position 43. 
HTML Agility Pack is full of bugs. I don't have much faith in it...

Comment: @user1978421: `<` isn't `?` or `/` is it?

Comment: Sorry, I see the problem why. It's because there is a & ahead

Answer (score 2):

LINQ to XML is only designed to parse XML, not HTML. In fact, `?` and `/` shouldn't cause a problem to LINQ to XML - although `&` in unexpected places will, along with unclosed or unbalanced tags.

You should use something like [HTML Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) or [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML, unless you know that the HTML you want to parse is *actually* valid XML.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Does HTML Tidy perform better than HTML Agility? HTML agility is so buggy. I have tried before.

Comment: @user1978421: I don't know - I haven't used either myself, but have heard good things about both. Perhaps the bugs that you ran into have been fixed?

Comment: hm... I am going to give it one more try